# PHP | При выполнении скрипта - выполняется цикл

Tags: php, циклы

Написал простой код. При запросе к нему через браузер - он выполняется овер дохера раз.
Задача кода: отправлять сообщение пользователю, используя VK API. По журналам, происходит масса однотипных запросов, хотя я лишь один раз загружаю страницу. Где можно искать ошибку вообще?

```
<?php

$randomId = mt_rand(1, 99999999); //Генерация рандомного числа

//Ключ доступа сообщества
define('ACCESS_TOKEN', 'ТОКЕН'); 

file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?user_id=1234&message=hello!&random_id=".$randomId."&access_token=".ACCESS_TOKEN."&v=5.60"); // Запрос к API
```

- `user_id` - идентификатор пользователя, которому отправлять сообщение;
- `message` - само сообщение;
- `random_id` - передача уникального числа;
- `access_token` - ключ доступа сообщества;
- `v` - версия API

Comment: каких запросов происходит масса то? к АПИ или к вашему файлу?

Comment: @teran на самом деле, не знаю. Скорее всего к api, так как даже после закрытия страницы со скрипом в браузере - мне продолжают приходить сообщения вконтакте от бота. Вряд ли поступает большое количество запросов к файлу.

Comment: дак вы к сообщению добавьте IP адрес клиента, вот и узнаете заодно откуда запросы сыпятся :)

Comment: @teran На самом деле да. Это помогло. Помогло убедиться в том, что главная проблема кода - я сам. Цикл был и он вызывался самим API VK. При запросе к API из моего кода - сообщество понимало, что было отправлено исходящее сообщение. О чём уведомляло мой скрипт через API, на что скрипт срабатывал и вызывался ещё бесконечное число раз. Подсветить IP адрес инициировавшего запрос, несомненно, стало ключом к решению проблемы :)

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле здесь нет никакого цикла. Возможно происходит задержка при соединении c сервером VK (медленный интернет, либо долгий ответ от сервера). Для проверки данной теории можете попробовать сделать тоже самое через CURL:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?user_id=1234&message=hello!&random_id=".$randomId."&access_token=".ACCESS_TOKEN."&v=5.60");
curl_exec($ch);
// Вывод будет направлен в браузер, т.к. мы не устанавливали параметр CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER в true
```